# Write conversion factors in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I would like to write the following conversion factor in LaTeX, I've been looking in different manuals and I can't find anything. I hope you can help me.

[image]

I have come to the following, but the problem is that I am not able to put spaces between spaces. And, ideally, things that are the same could be crossed out:

`30 mL dis \times \frac{0,1 mol NaOH}{10^{3} mL} \times  ...`

Comment: What is “HftK”?

Comment: What have you been able to do so far?  Most of this isn't too difficult and would only take a little bit of TeX knowledge.  The units (see `siunitx`) and chemistry (possibly `chemfig`) would be a little more challenging, but if you can give us a starting point, that'd be nice.

Comment: It's an abbreviation I use so I don't have to write potassium hydrogen phthalate

Comment: @Teepeemm I just edited it so I can see what I've done.

Comment: It would be best if you typed in the [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497) from `\documentclass` through `\end{document}` that gives the above equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `siunitx` for the units and numbers, with `mhchem` for the name of substances.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\[
\SI{30}{\milli\liter}\,\mathrm{dis.}\cdot
\frac{\SI{0,1}{\mol}\,\ce{NaOH}}{\SI{e3}{\milli\liter}\,\mathrm{dis.}}\cdot
\frac{\SI{1}{\mol}\,\ce{HftK}}{\SI{1}{\mol}\,\ce{NaOH}}\cdot
\frac{\SI{204,23}{\mol}\,\ce{HftK}}{\SI{1}{\mol}\,\ce{HftK}}=
\SI{0,61269}{\gram}\,\ce{HftK}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]