# Equation with Fractions and with Text and Numbers

Tags: math-mode

I need to introduce the following formula in a Latex document, I've been consulting several online manuals, but I can't find anything.
I hope you can help me.

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What is the difference to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463534/?

Answer (score 3):

I use `\text` from `amsmath` package and `\unit` from `units` package. The rest is *Do-It-For-Me*.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
% \, --> half space 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{X\,mL Something}}{\text{X\,mL Something}} \times \frac{\text{X\,mL Something}}{\text{X\,mL Something}} \times \frac{\text{\unit[3]{g} Something}}{\text{\unit[3]{g} Something}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]